# Windows 10 upgrade killed my bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

I upgraded my work laptop lenovo T540P from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. There were some issues like DisplayLink not working or a BSOD in Synatpics Touchpad driver which were all resolved by using the lenovo System Update to update the drivers.

But I have completely lost Bluetooth and the System Update hasn't helped with that. Some observations:

- There is no Bluetooth section in Settings/Devices
- Device Manager shows an "Unknown Device" under Other Devices, which has the error "The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)". There is no Bluetooth device anywhere in device manager
- Every run of Lenovo System Update prompts for installing "Intel Bluetooth Device Software - Initial Install - 10[64]", even after installing it
- Installing Bluetooth drivers downloaded from Lenovo, outside the System Update tool didn't help either
- Lenovo Enterprise Support recommends reverting to Windows 8.1

If I buy an external Bluetooth dongle, will it be recognized or can I expect to have similar issues with it as well?

Comment: Have you tried downloading/installing the Bluetooth driver manually, outside of the ThinkVantage System Update tool? There are certainly Windows 10 versions of the driver. http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t540p

Comment: Yes I did, actually even before I tried the update tool. Same result.

Comment: You should edit your original post to include that, it will help others. Do you have any Windows updates? Does the Bluetooth device appear in BIOS?

Comment: Thanks @root. I have updated my post, I will check the BIOS now.

Comment: There is no Bluetooth anywhere in BIOS/Config tab. But my Bluetooth was working before 8.1 to 10 Upgrade.

Comment: Have you updated the chipset driver to the right version?

Comment: @DrZoo I have not updated the chipset driver. Would that be required along with Windows 10 Upgrade?

Comment: You should update your major drivers to the current version that was built for Windows 10. I'd start with updating chipset drivers, restart your PC, then try installing the Bluetooth drivers again. I just did a quick Google search to let you know [you're not the only one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/where-did-my-bluetooth-go-after-updating-to/9f754aa5-3376-47aa-8968-c3ebccded62d?auth=1)

Comment: Thanks @DrZoo. At the Lenovo [T540P page](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t540p?TabName=Downloads&linkTrack&beta=false) the Chipset component has two entries for Intel Management Engine and two for Intel Chipset Driver for Windows. Of the latter, the one with T540P is version 9.4.0.1026 while my regkey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Intel\Infinst gives a higher 9.4.0.1027! (1/2)

Comment: The other entry is version  10.1.1.8. For checking installed version it directs me to Device Manager/System Devices/Mobile 5th Generation Intel(R) Core(TM) Thermal Management Controller-9CA4, which does not exist for me. Should I try to install this? (2/2)

Comment: What do you mean by it does not exist for me? Install the v10.1.1.8 chipset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37537/discussion-between-drzoo-and-miserable-variable).

Comment: Thanks @DrZoo for your help in chat. Unfortunately even after installing the new chipset and then the bluetooth driver (which reported success) the situation is exactly as before -- no Bluetooth in Settings/Devices, Unknown device in device manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded to W10 in Nov 2015, and intel bluetooth worked fine then. Today I experience the same problem as you do. I have a pending intel bt update in the windows update queue that fails to install consistently. I suspect it is the culprit.
I'll try a clean re-install of W10 (boot from DVD, reformat) soon and will let everyone know here.
I dual boot linux on this machine. BT works fine there - i.e. it's not a hardware issue.

I reinstalled my W10 last night. BT works fine by installing a recent intel bluetooth driver from windows update. I suspect the culprit is the intel prowireless bluetooth driver 17.0.1405.0464 that I inherited from W81. I could not remove this software. 
Once again, MS operating system needs a clean install to work correctly.